# ActionBar click Switchbutton Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

there is problem with clicking switchbutton on actionbar. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.abc);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.testing);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.abc:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABOUT.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My menu: menu_main

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/test"
    android:title=""/>
```

And layout for switchbutton:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
```

When I click on switch button this toast isn't showing. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Should it ???

Toast message is displayed when you select the item with id:abc from the options menu.

in your code there is no evidence of an action to be fired when you click the switch button.

for every  button - switch button - image button etc...   you should create the button object and set an action to perform when the button is clicked.

the method onOptionsItemSelected  handle just the standars options menu.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//declare the global variable switchcompat
 SwitchCompat switchCompat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //contruct the object from yhe one declared in the xml
    switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);

    //set the onClickListener that define what to do when the view is                  clicked
    switchCompat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some message here",                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.abc);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.testing);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.abc:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABOUT.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't defined an `OnTouchListener` for your `SwitchCompat` view.

Change your `onCreate` method code to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
        switchCompat.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ABOUT.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

Comment: when I added it: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.setOnClickListener